# Limit SharePoint search results to selectProperties

Tags: javascript, rest, api, search, sharepoint

I would like to get some data using SharePoint Search REST API. Using this query i get correct data:

```
http://mySharePoint/sites/mySiteCollection/_api/search/query?querytext='*ac*'&rowlimit=100&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

but I would like to limit this results to search only in few properties, something like this: `Title == *ac* || Description == *ac*` 
Is this possible to manage it?

Comment: Have you done /GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$top=100

There is more here:
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

Comment: I asked about Search Rest API, which is using Search Service. I wanna get data from different lists by one query, and then handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what is problem. SharePoint Search can't handle matching patterns inside word or postfixes. It can only proceed prefixes. So, searching things like abc* is available, but *abc or *abc* not.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
http://mySharePoint/sites/mySiteCollection/_api/search/query?querytext='(Title=*ac* OR Description=*ac*)'&rowlimit=100&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

Download https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool  and try it yourself.

Comment: try with contains '(Title:ac* OR Description:ac*)'